# How to display a text value in the 3dview that shows the value of the width in the bevel modifier while I'm changing it?

Tags: python, scripting

I wanted to draw a text value on the screen when I change the value of a modifier, for example I need the value of the solidify thickness to show up on the 3d view screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally did it, well it took some time but I got to forgot adding the answer.

```
blf.draw(font_id, str(context.active_object.modifiers["Bevel"].width))
```